# is there a way to make my jquery code more efficient?

Tags: jquery

is there a way to make my code run smoother and more efficient?

```
var headerH = $("#header").height();
var winH = $(window).height();
var newH = winH - headerH;
$("#wrap").css({ 'height' : newH + 'px' });
$(window).resize(function() {
    var _headerH = $("#header").height();
    var _winH = $(window).height();
    var _newH = _winH - _headerH;
    $("#wrap").css({ 'height' : _newH + 'px' });
});
//--Expand Panel
$(".open-menu").live('click', function(){
    $("#wrap").css({ 'height' : newH + 'px' });
    $(".mini-menu").fadeOut(500);
    $("#headerCompany").animate({
        marginLeft: '+=142'
    }, 650);
    $("#avatar_box").fadeIn(650);
    $("#pinboard").fadeIn(550);
    $("div#centerHeader").slideDown("slow");
    $("#toggle-pinboard a").removeClass("open-menu").addClass("close-menu");
    return false;
});
// Collapse Panel
$(".close-menu").live('click', function(){
    $("#wrap").css({ 'height' : newH + 'px' });
    $("#avatar_box").fadeOut(550);
    $("#pinboard").fadeOut(550);
    $("#headerCompany").animate({
        marginLeft: '-=142'
    }, 650);
    $("div#centerHeader").slideUp(750).delay(300);
    $.post('resources/ajax/ajax.php', {
        action: 'mini_menu'
    }, function(menu){
        $("#mini-menu").hide().html(menu).addClass("mini-menu").fadeIn(1500);
    });
    $("#toggle-pinboard a").removeClass("close-menu").addClass("open-menu");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, the public beta for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ starts in a couple days.

Comment: If you don't have to worry about `close-menu` or `open-menu` being written to the page outside of the initial page load, then do away with using `live()`.

Comment: @Josh - In a sense I do because when you click on the button that toggles the open/close I'm removing and adding the classes that allow for a re-toggle

Comment: If you could change the classes so that you aren't swapping in/out the selector classes you could do away with `.live()`.  Unless you are swapping content with an ajax call, you should reconsider the use of live due to how it works.  As it was explained to me, every time there is a click event anywhere on the page it will have to check to see if the element clicked matches the selector with the live event attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to get rid of the 'live' is to do something like this:

```
$("#toggle-pinboard a").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open-menu')) {
        // close menu code
    }
    else {
        // open menu code
    }
}
```